# localhost session cookies do not work anymore in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, localhost, session-cookies

In Internet Explorer I was testing some things with Privacy security settings. After finishing my testing (I restored all settings, security setting back to Normal) my localhost in Internet Explorer doesn't accept cookies (session and normal) anymore.

Has anyone had this problem and doe anyone know how to repair this?

Strange thing: if I try 127.0.0.1 the cookies do work. I have nothing changed in my host file....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working again. I restored Internet Explorer to its default settings en deleted al my personal settings.